# Notifications in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, notifications, android-5.0-lollipop

I used `NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()` in previous android versions and everything was good. The same application in Lollipop makes me sad:

Big Notification looks good:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUjCx.png

And small is bad:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dksJv.png

Looks like layout's height equals big notification height and small layout is just centered vertical on this big height though small layout height is `match_parent`. Is there some change happened with android in lollipop or am I miss something obvious?

Thanks in advance.

**UPD 1.**
Main lines of code here:
`mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle());
   notification = mBuilder.build();
   notification.bigContentView = bigView;`

Amusing point here is that if I remove last line then small notification looks like there is no problem. I tried to change bigView layout but it works like I described. If big notification becomes bigger in height then I don't see small notificatin at all, it's padding from top increases.

Comment: I customize my notifications, I would start looking at the lollipop sources some attributes have changed.

Comment: post your code please